# What is the difference between the two?

Tags: java, arraylist

i am using an user-defined **arrayList** and adding elements to it from `settergetter` class and there are 2 scenarios

## using for loop

nam[] and em[] are arrays which are already declared and have values in them

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    settergetter sg = new settergetter();
    sg.setName(nam[i]);
    sg.setEmail(em[i]);
    a1.add(sg);
  }
```

in this case when i iterate i get correct ans as i want .. ie 1st element and then 2nd and so on

### normal case

in this case i create 2 objects of settergetter class and add it to the arraylist

```
  settergetter sg = new settergetter();
  sg.setName("amol");
  sg.setEmail("amol@9372");
  a1.add(sg);
  settergetter sg1 = new settergetter();
  sg.setName("robin");
  sg.setEmail("robin@9372");
  a1.add(sg1);
```

**in this case the ans i get is only of the last object added ie robin**

in both the cases i am creating different instances of the class

i am using iterator as :

```
  Iterator itr=a1.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext())
  {
     settergetter element = (settergetter) itr.next();
     System.out.println(element.getName());
     System.out.println(element.getEmail());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you closely look, you are still setting to `sg`, actually you named your second instance as `sg1`. Set to `sg1` instance and it works.

```
 settergetter sg1 = new settergetter();
  sg.setName("robin");
  sg.setEmail("robin@9372");
  a1.add(sg1);
```

That should be

```
settergetter sg1 = new settergetter();
  sg1.setName("robin");  // here 
  sg1.setEmail("robin@9372"); // here 
  a1.add(sg1);
```